# Условия проверки пересечения двух отрезков

Tags: геометрия

> Есть 2 отрезка AB и CD заданное своими координатами. Найти точку пересечения этих отрезков.

1. Составляю уравнения прямых (x-x1)/(x2-x1) и (y-y1)/(y2-y1)
2. Решаю систему уравнения и нахожу "x" и "y" (пусть это будет точка E)
3. Проверяю, чтобы отрезки AE и EB, а также CE и ED были соноправленными. 
   Если они являются таковыми, значит точка E является точкой пересечения отрезков.

Достаточно ли этих трех условий, чтобы утверждать, что точка E является точкой пересечения этих отрезков?

Если недостаточно, напишите, пожалуйста, какие еще необходимо проверить условия, либо другой более правильный метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если при решении системы уравнений учитывается случай параллельных прямых (в таком случае решений нет или их бесконечное количество при совпадении прямых), то этих условий достаточно.

Есть методы проверки факта пересечения, не требующие нахождения самой точки пересечения. Например, алгоритм, который проверяет, что концы одного отрезка лежат по разные стороны от прямой, включающей второй отрезок, и концы второго отрезка лежат по разные стороны от прямой, включающей первый отрезок. При этом сравниваются знаки векторных произведений `AB x AC и AB x AD, CD x CA и CD x CB`