# Как определить наличие общих точек двух отрезков? СИ

Tags: c

Даны вещественные числа x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4.

Определите, имеет ли отрезок с концами (x1, y1) и (x2, y2) общие точки с отрезком с концами (x3, y3) и (x4, y4).

Ввод

В первой строке содержатся вещественные числа x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 – координаты концов отрезков.

Вывод

Вывести "Yes", если отрезки имеют общие точки, и "No" в противном случае.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{float x1, y1,x2, y2,x3, y3,x4, y4,x,y;
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &x1, &y1,&x2, &y2,&x3, &y3,&x4, &y4);
x=((x1*y2-x2*y1)*(x4-x3)-(x3*y4-x4*y3)*(x2-x1))/((y1-y2)*(x4-x3)-(y3-y4)*(x2-x1));
y=((y3-y4)*x-(x3*y4-x4*y3))/(x4-x3);
if (((x1<=x)&&(x2>=x)&&(x3<=x)&&(x4 >=x))||((y1<=y)&&(y2>=y)&&(y3<=y) &&(y4>=y))){
    printf("Yes");
}
else{
    printf("No");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое x и y?

Comment: Координаты пересечения отрезков

Comment: Для определения факта пересечения точку искать не нужно

Comment: А что нужно сделать?

Comment: [Вот например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814147/291659), но я думаю, есть и более полные ответы с кодом

Comment: [Вот, кстати, у гиков правильная функция](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В формуле посчёта координат есть ошибка, но я не могу ее исправить так как непонятно откуда была взята формула. Но есть альтернативный вариант решения с помощью ориентированной площади треугольника:

```
if (intersect(x1, x2, x3, x4) && intersect(y1, y2, y3, y4)
        && area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) * area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x4, y4) <= 0
        && area(x3, y3, x4, y4, x1, y1) * area(x3, y3, x4, y4, x2, y2) <= 0) {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else{
        printf("No");
    }
```

, где

```
#define swap(a, b) a ^= b, b ^= a, a ^= b;

int area (float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, float cx, float cy) {
    return (bx - ax) * (cy - ay) - (by - ay) * (cx - ax);
}
 
int intersect (int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a > b)  swap (a, b);
    if (c > d)  swap (c, d);
    return (a > c ? a : c) <= (b < d ? b : d);
}
```